# How to read and send resource?

Tags: php

I need to generate and send log data to the mail in `csv` format. Here is my code:

```
public function sendMail(){
    $csv = $this->createCSV();
    $subject = $this->getMessage('subject');
    $message = $this->getMessage('message');
    $headers = $this->generateHeaders($csv, $message);

    mail('my_mail@gmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
}

private function createCSV(){
    $data = $this->getAVG();

    $csv = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

    // long statistics generation

    fclose($csv);

    return $csv;
}

private function generateHeaders($file, $message){
    $boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$boundary."\"\r\n";  
    $headers .= 'From: noreplay@'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."\r\n";

    $headers .= '--'.$boundary."\r\n";

    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $headers .= "\r\n";
    $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));

    $headers .= '--'.$boundary."\r\n";

    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/csv; name=\"ServersLogs.csv\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"ServersLogs.csv\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "\r\n";
    $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode(readfile($file)));

    $headers .= "\r\n--".$boundary."--\r\n"; 

    return $headers;
}
```

The problem is that i cant save file on the server, so i use [php://](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php), but after it can't read a file...

Comment: Have you tried saving files on `/tmp`? You should have permissions over there.

Answer (score 0):

`$csv = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');` - this line will create resource (handler), it's not name of file.

`fclose($csv);` - in this line resource is closed and it can't be used anymore.
So `return $csv;` will not return anything usable.

`readfile($file)` - this function require filename as a first argument, not handler of closed resource.

I don't see why at all you need file or temporary memory storage - just use variable (not global). Anyway whole data will be in memory.

Comment: it's pretty simple to create csv without this function.

Answer (score 0):

You should close() your file after generateHeaders() call and use fread() instead of readfile(). Don't forget to fseek($file, 0, SEEK_SET) before reading.

By the way, you save your data to a temporary file just to read it back again in generateHeaders(). Why don't you just pass generated statistics data to generateHeaders() instead of $file resource?